# Javascript: I have multiple trigger button on a page, but they all trigger the last event

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage with several buttons. Those buttons trigger a modal with content in it. Each button is associated with a unique modal with unique content in it.

The problem is every button triggers the modal associated with the last button at the bottom of the page.

Each button and modal have a unique id, so I don't understand why this is happening.

Here's the code I used to create each of those buttons.

Thank you for your help!

```js
// JS CODE FOR THE FIRST MODAL 

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("button-1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close-1");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
// When the user press ESC key, close the modal
window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
// JS CODE FOR THE SECOND MODAL 

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("button-2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close-2");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
// When the user press ESC key, close the modal
window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1001; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white; 
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal #1 -->
<a id="button-1">Modal #1</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="close-1" class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>I'm the text of the first modal</p>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal #2 -->
<a id="button-2">Modal #2</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="modal-2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span id="close-2" class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>I'm the text of the second modal</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a loop anywhere? The code you posted doesn't illustrate the problem you're describing in full.

Comment: Could you post a fuller working example? It would be helpful to see how you are generating the buttons and the modals since, as it is right now, there can only be one modal and one button since they're using generic ids.

Comment: Hi @Phix, as you requested I added a second modal so you can see the issue here. As you will see, the second modal is opening whether you click on the first trigger. Thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, as you requested I added a second modal so you can see the issue here. As you will see, the second modal is opening whether you click on the first trigger. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
// JS CODE FOR THE FIRST MODAL

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-1');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("button-1");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("close-1");

// Get the modal
var modal2 = document.getElementById('modal-2');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn2 = document.getElementById("button-2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span2 = document.getElementById("close-2");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }else if (event.target == modal2) {
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
// When the user press ESC key, close the modal
window.onkeydown = function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode == 27 ) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        modal2.style.display = "none";
    }
};

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
```

Please update your script like this, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

isn't it because you miss to add some event stopPropagation ?

(and I think it is a bad idea to name a JS vaviable "span", this a name of html tag)

and it shoud be more clear to code on this way (same event for serveral elements)

```js
    var ActionCloseID = ['modal', 'button', 'close'];
    document.onclick = function(e) {
        if (ActionCloseID.includes(e.target.id) ) {
            e.stopPropagation();                  
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```